# How do I delete an Azure Enterprise Application given the delete button is disabled?

Tags: azure

I have deleted one of my free subscriptions from Azure. Now I want to delete the Directory that was associated with it.

However when I try to delete the directory a blade appears with a message link that I need to Remove all resources

If I click the link I see that the resource preventing the deletion is my cancelled subscription with status Disabled.

[image: as shown here]

How do I delete the directory?

[Update]

I deleted the users,
Now disconcertingly the Directory delete screen shows that I have associated Enterprise applications.
Where did they come from ?

[image: associated Enterprise Applications]

Drilling in I see the associated application is Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services.

There is no button to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to delete Team Services, since I could not delete it via the portal UI  the following steps worked ( Thank you Microsoft support).

1. Find the related object ID for your application You can find it in
   Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services -> Properties -> Object ID
   Copy this object ID.
2. Use Azure AD PowerShell command, run the PowerShell with

   ```
   install-module azuread

   connect-azuread -TenantId “your tenant ID
   ```

For example

```
Connect-azuread –TenantId “your tenant id”
```

This is the tenant id where the application is, not the application object ID.

```
Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId “app object ID”
```

This is the app object id which we copied previously, not the tenant object ID.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - again, Azure Dev Ops (the new name for Visual Studio Team System) kept turning up.

In the Azure portal, I opened the Enterprise Application entry for the errant application, went to Properties, and selected **"No" for "Enabled for users enabled to sign-in".**  (I couldn't delete the application as the button was grayed out).

I then saved changes and was then able to delete the Azure AD Tenant (despite not actually deleting the registration.)

Comment: Thanks, this solution was easier and worked like a charm